# How to move files that contains certain message on it to another folder (Unix Korn Shell)

Tags: list, unix, grep, message, move

I'm trying to move some files that contain message "File was not FOUND" on it and I'm getting a result but I have to move all of them only with 1 line of code, at this point I have got now the files names, but can't move to another directory.

I have done this

```
mv $(grep "File was not FOUND" FilesToMove/Test* | cut -d ":" -f1) TargetDirectory
```

when I execute only this line `grep "File was not FOUND" FilesToMove/Test* | cut -d ":" -f1` I'm geting the files that I want, but when I do with the `mv` to the target directory I got `mv: FilesToMove/Test_file: No such file or directory`

Do you have any suggestion? I also tried with:

`grep "File was not FOUND" FilesToMove/Test* | cut -d ":" -f1 | xargs mv -t TargetDirectory`

Also is not working, i'm getting this:

`mv: unknown option -- t
usage: mv [-bfhinuv] [-S suff] source target
       mv [-bfhinuv] [-S suff] source ... directory`

any idea?

Comment: why do you expect `mv -t` to work? Read the usage summary for `mv` (or the `man` page). Do you see a `-t` option? Search here for other `xargs` Qs to see some working examples. Good luck.

Comment: is working without xargs and -t option, I did the anwer commented below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" FilesToMove/Test*) TargetDirectory
```

Comment: `mv: -: No such file or directory`